# AddFontResource does not install the font correctly

Tags: c++, windows, fonts

I use AddFontResourceW(_T("C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyFont.ttf")); to install 2 fonts from my 64-bit C++ app.

The return value is 1, but in the app the font is displayed 10 times smaller and look like Sans Serif (not my font).

If I manually install the font in Windows, then it is displayed correctly in the app.

I have tried AddFontResourceEx, but the same result. I also have tried to copy the TTF font file in C:\Windows\Fonts with my app installer and then call AddFontResource(_T("myfont.ttf")); and the same result.

If I don't call the AddFontResource at all, then the font is substituted with Arial with the correct size.

Tested in 64-bit Windows 7, 10 and Windows 2012 Server.

I have tried with Oswald font and Ubuntu, but I get the same results.

Comment: The display size of a font has nothing to do with how it is installed, and everything to do with how your app's UI code loads and configures the font at runtime.

Comment: The font also is not the correct font, when it is displayed smaller. And if I install the font manually then it displays the correct font and size.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by copying the font to C:\Windows\Fonts then add it to registry and then AddFontResource, otherwise it does not display the font correctly. Using it as a temporary font resource it does not work.